# How to extract nested text in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to extract a paragraph of brand description on this website using Scrapy:
http://us.asos.com/hope-and-ivy/hope-ivy-dotty-mesh-midi-dress-with-ruffle-detail/prd/8663409?clr=black&cid=2623&pgesize=36&pge=0&totalstyles=627&gridsize=3&gridrow=1&gridcolumn=1

The HTML element looks like this:

```
<div class="brand-description">
  <h4>Brand</h4>
  <span>"Prom queens and wedding guests, claim the best-dressed title in "
    <a href="/Women/A-To-Z-Of-Brands/Hope-And-Ivy/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=21368">
      <strong>"Hope and Ivy's"</strong>
    </a> 
    "occasion-ready collection. Shop its notice-me styles for hand-painted florals, Bardot necklines and figure-flattering pencil dresses."
  </span>
</div>
```

My desired result is:

"Prom queens and wedding guests, claim the best-dressed title in Hope and Ivy's occasion-ready collection. Shop its notice-me styles for hand-painted florals, Bardot necklines and figure-flattering pencil dresses."

I tried this method:

```
response.css("div.brand-description span::text").extract()
```

However, the text list I got is missing those inside the "strong" tag, which is "Hope and Ivy's":

```
['Prom queens and wedding guests, claim the best-dressed title in ',  ' occasion-ready collection. Shop its notice-me styles for hand-painted florals, Bardot necklines and figure-flattering pencil dresses.']
```

My question is, can I get the plain text without the attention to the "href" tag?

Comment: try taking this //div[@class="brand-description"]/div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still might have to do some post-processing, but this is probably the best you can do:

```
response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="brand-description"]/span)').extract_first()
```

which will give you

```
u'"Prom queens and wedding guests, claim the best-dressed title in " "Hope and Ivy\'s" "occasion-ready collection. Shop its notice-me styles for hand-painted florals, Bardot necklines and figure-flattering pencil dresses."'
```

Comment: It took me a lot of effort to find a solution for "strong" tags within text. If you use "css-selectors" you can't work with "normalize-space", so I use [vezunchik's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106850/vezunchik) solution (from w3lib.html import remove_tags), whose discussion you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779773/is-there-a-way-to-extract-text-along-with-text-links-in-scrapy-using-css/55790178#55790178)