# Is there a way to extract text along with text-links in Scrapy using CSS?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm brand new to Scrapy. I have learned how to use `response.css()` for reading specific aspects from a web page, and am avoiding learning the xpath system. It seems to do the exact same thing, but in a different format (correct me if I'm wrong)

The site I'm scraping has long paragraphs of text, with an occasional linked text right in the middle. This sentence with a [link to a picture of a dog](https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p720x720/24899859_10155212763208063_577851342204713633_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&oh=b714419c6536bc33ce6c91f923e549d4&oe=5D42C928) is an example. I'm not sure if there is a way to have a spider read the text, with links in place (I've only been using `response.css("p::text").extract()`)

Is there a way, using CSS (preferably) or xpath that I can grab all text in the paragraphs including the link-embedded text, without moving the links or link-text out of the sentence? The wording is difficult on this so apologies if I need to re-explain or give an example.

edit: some clarification is needed, this was poorly explained initially. A statement in this webpage can look like:
`<p>My sentence has a <a href="https://www.google.com">link to google</a> in it.</p>`
But when you use `response.css("p::text").extract()`, that sentence would show up as the list ["My sentence has a ","in it."], completely negating the text in the link. My goal is to get: ["My sentence has a link to google in it."]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by keeping the links, and not just the link text, in the paragraph? How would you like to extract `<p>This <a href="#">paragraph</a> has a link.</p>`?

Comment: @Gallaecio I would like to extract that as "This paragraph has a link." But by just using ```response.css("p::text").extract()```, the extracted statement would look like ["This", "has a link."] or so that's what it's been doing so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to extract text with this expression:

```
>>> txt = """<p>My sentence has a <a href="https://www.google.com">link to google</a> in it.</p>"""
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> sel.css('p ::text').extract()
[u'My sentence has a ', u'link to google', u' in it.']
>>> ' '.join(sel.css('p ::text').extract())
u'My sentence has a  link to google  in it.'
```

Or, for example, use w3lib.html library to clean html tags from your response. In this way:

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
with_tags = response.css("p").get()
clean_text = remove_tags(with_tags)
```

But first variant looks shorter and more readable.

Comment: So if you see the post I made, the first variant is what I've been doing, but it neglects to get any <a href>'s in the middle of a <p>. It just gets the text around the link. However I will look into w3lib, thanks for the info.

Comment: Nope, check the space in the middle of my css selector. I've added some example to first variant to make it more clean.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even notice the space in the selector. I'll give that a try and report back. Sorry, my comment looks real sassy now. How does adding the space change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use [html-text](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text) after extracting the whole paragraph:

```py
from html_text import extract_text

for paragraph in response.css('p'):
    html = paragraph.get()
    text = extract_text(html)
```