# How can I get text from htmlresponse for all br tag by xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I use scrapy to get a object with type htmlresponse for example:

```
<p class="post">
        line1<br />
        line2<br />
        line3<br />
</p>
<p class="post">
        line4<br />
        line5<br />
        line6<br />
</p>
```

and I want get all text between p,but I try:

```
response.xpath('//p[@class="post"]/text()').extract()
```

but the result have 6 lines from line1 to line6,and I want to get all text between a p tag,for example:
    #first p
    line1
    line2
    line3
    #second p
    line4
    line5
    line6
How can I do it?

Comment: are you sing xslt 1.0/

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/55805214/939364 work for your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have to use XPath? BS4 is a good solution. So is SimplifiedDoc

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html='''<p class="post">
        line1<br />
        line2<br />
        line3<br />
</p>
<p class="post">
        line4<br />
        line5<br />
        line6<br />
</p>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
p = doc.getElementsByClass('post')
for x in p:
  print (x.html)
  print (doc.removeHtml(x.html,' '))
```

result:

```
line1<br />line2<br />line3<br />
line1 line2 line3
line4<br />line5<br />line6<br />
line4 line5 line6
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **xslt 2.0**, you can use `string-join` function.

```
string-join(//p[@class="post"]/text())
```

Comment: I am using scrapy to get a web page,and that will response a object with type htmlresponse,can I use xslt for it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use BeautifulSoup too for parse html(pip install BeautifulSoup4)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p class="post">
        line1<br />
        line2<br />
        line3<br />
</p>
<p class="post">
        line4<br />
        line5<br />
        line6<br />
</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
p=soup.find_all('p')
for x in p:
  print(x.text)
```

result :

```
line1
line2
line3


line4
line5
line6
```

Comment: I know this way to get all text from tag p,but I using scrapy to get a web page that response a object with type htmlresponse.
Maybe I can process it by bs4,but I want to process
it by xpath if that have a method.

Comment: @陳建伊 yes , maybe  just for parse you can use bs4

Answer (score 0):

Simply write `response.css('p ::text').extract()` .                              You can also use the class attribute
`response.css('.post ::text').extract()`

Answer (score 0):

With scrapy selectors you need something like this:

```
result = [[line.strip("\n ") for line in p_tag.css("*::text").extract() if line.strip("\n ")]
          for p_tag in response.css("p.post")]

#result= [['line1', 'line2', 'line3'], ['line4', 'line5', 'line6']]
```